# How is this possible to create multiple plots?

Tags: pine-script

So in the example below this indicator plots multiple lines when a multiplier is used example:

Multiplier x 1 = plots one line
Multiplier x 2 = plots two lines
and so on..

This example is using Multiplier X 4 = plots 4 lines.

I'm curious if anyone with pinescript experience can chime in how this is possible?  Thanks

[image: PLOT EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
//@version=4 
study("My Script", overlay=true)

smaLength   = input(20, minval=1)
offset      = input( 5, minval=1)
multiplier  = input( 3, minval=1, maxval=4)

mySMA = sma(close, 20)

plot(multiplier >= 1 ? mySMA + offset * 1 : na)
plot(multiplier >= 2 ? mySMA + offset * 2 : na)
plot(multiplier >= 3 ? mySMA + offset * 3 : na)
plot(multiplier >= 4 ? mySMA + offset * 4 : na)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  It's close but how would you implement in say this example vwap?  https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/more-pine-functions-support-dynamic-length-arguments-22719/